# ¿Cómo conseguir parámetros de cada objeto de una lista de objetos en JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación web en Python con Django y MongoDB. Estoy utilizando jQCloud (JavaScript) para hacer una nube de palabras. Devuelvo desde la vista (view.py) una lista de objetos `([<Words: Words object>, <Words: Words object>, <Words: Words object>, ...])`, y llegan correctamente al html (he probado esto haciendo una tabla y sacando los datos de cada objeto), pero luego no se cómo hacer en JavaScript que me saque los dos valores (palabra y repeticiones) de cada objeto words.

```
<div style="width:90%; height: 70%;" id="demo"></div>
<script>
    for (word in words){
        var w = [{text: {{"word.palabra"}}, weight:{{"word.repeticiones"}}}];
    }

    $(function() {
        $('#demo').jQCloud(w);
    });              
</script>
```

Los datos llegan al html correctamente como se puede ver en la siguiente tabla:
[image: Tabla con datos de la base de datos de MongoDB de la colección 'words']

El views.py es:

```
def profile(request):
    Context = RequestContext(request)
    if request.POST.get('search'):
        w = Words.objects.all()
        w.delete()
        wordcount = {}
        for item in search:
            t = item.text
            tokenizer = TweetTokenizer(preserve_case=False, strip_handles=True, reduce_len=True)
            tweet_tokens = tokenizer.tokenize(t)
            tweets_clean = []

            for word in total_tokens:
                if word not in wordcount:
                   wordcount[word] = 1
                else:
                   wordcount[word] += 1

            word_counter = collections.Counter(wordcount)

            for word, count in word_counter.most_common(5): 
                print(word, ": ", count)
                words = Words(palabra=word, repeticiones=count)
                words.save()
            template = 'blog/data.html'

            words = Words.objects.all()

            params = {'sentiments': sentiments, 'words':words, 'users':users}
    elif request.method == 'GET':
        template = 'blog/tweet.html'
        params = { 'None': None  }
    return render(request, template, params)
```

Y los estoy cogiendo de la siguiente manera:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <script src="../../static/js/Chart.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../../static/js/utils.js"></script>

    <script src="../../static/startbootstrap-new-age-gh-pages/vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../../static/js/jqcloud.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../static/css/jqcloud.min.css">
</head>
<body>  
    <h2 class="text-left">Profile</h2>
                <div class="table-responsive" >
                    <table class="table table-hover table-responsive" id="tabla" WIDTH="100%">
                        <thead>
                            <tr align="CENTER">                                 
                                <th NOWRAP class="bg-info text-center">Positivo</th>
                                <th NOWRAP class="bg-info text-center">Negativo</th>
                                <th NOWRAP class="bg-info text-center">Neutro</th>

                            </tr>
                        </thead>

                        <tbody>
                            <tr align="CENTER">                                 
                                <td  NOWRAP>{{sentiments.positive}}</td>
                                <td  NOWRAP>{{sentiments.negative}}</td>
                                <td  NOWRAP>{{sentiments.neutral}}</td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>                    

                </div>

                <div class="table-responsive" >
                    <table class="table table-hover table-responsive" id="tabla" WIDTH="100%">
                        <thead>
                            <tr align="CENTER">                                 
                                <th NOWRAP class="bg-info text-center">Palabra</th>
                                <th NOWRAP class="bg-info text-center">Repeticiones</th>


                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                            {% for word in words %}
                        <tbody>
                            <tr align="CENTER">                                 
                                <td  NOWRAP>{{word.palabra}}</td>
                                <td  NOWRAP>{{word.repeticiones}}</td>

                            </tr>
                            {% empty %}
                                <p>Sorry, no words in this list.</p>                                    

                            {% endfor %}                                
                        </tbody>

                    </table>                    
                </div>
                <div class="table-responsive" >
                    <table class="table table-hover table-responsive" id="tabla" WIDTH="100%">
                        <thead>
                            <tr align="CENTER">                                 
                                <th NOWRAP class="bg-info text-center">Seguidores</th>
                                <th NOWRAP class="bg-info text-center">Usuarios</th>


                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                            {% for user in users %}
                        <tbody>
                            <tr align="CENTER">                                 
                                <td  NOWRAP>{{user.followers}}</td>
                                <td  NOWRAP>{{user.username}}</td>

                            </tr>
                            {% empty %}
                                <p>Sorry, no users in this list.</p>                                    

                            {% endfor %}                                
                        </tbody>


                    </table>                    
                </div>


                <div id="canvas-holder" style="width:40%">
                    <canvas id="chart-area"></canvas>
                </div>

                <script>

                        var positive = "{{sentiments.positive}}";
                        var positiveScalingFactor = function() {
                            return Math.round(positive * 100);
                        };
                        var negative = "{{sentiments.negative}}";
                        var negativeScalingFactor = function() {
                            return Math.round(negative * 100);
                        };
                        var neutral = "{{sentiments.neutral}}";
                        var neutralScalingFactor = function() {
                            return Math.round(neutral * 100);
                        };


                        var config = {
                            type: 'pie',
                            data: {
                                datasets: [{
                                    data: [
                                        negativeScalingFactor(),
                                        neutralScalingFactor(),
                                        positiveScalingFactor(),
                                    ],
                                    backgroundColor: [
                                        window.chartColors.red,
                                        window.chartColors.blue,
                                        window.chartColors.green,
                                    ],
                                    label: 'Dataset 1'
                                }],
                                labels: [
                                    'Negativos',
                                    'Neutros',
                                    'Positivos'
                                ]
                            },
                            options: {
                                responsive: true
                            }
                        };

                        window.onload = function() {
                            var ctx = document.getElementById('chart-area').getContext('2d');
                            window.myPie = new Chart(ctx, config);
                        };


                </script>
            <div style="width:90%; height: 70%;" id="demo"></div>
            <script> 
            //Supongamos que la siguiente lista la obtienes de tu backend
                const words = {{words}};
                // creamos el array que pasaremos como parametro
                let words_array = [];
                //recorremos la lista recibida (usamos for ... of)
                //console.log("{{words}}");



                for(word of words) {
                  //usamos el método push de nuestro array para insertar los objetos
                  words_array.push({text: word.palabra, weight: word.repeticiones});

                }
                $(function() {
                  //ejecutamos la función jQCloud y le pasamos el array de elementos
                  $('#demo').jQCloud(words_array);
                  console.log(words_array);
                });
            </script>


</body>
```

Comment: ¿Puedes poner la estructura del objeto que recibes?

Comment: Claro, el objeto 'words' que contiene un String que es 'palabra' y un integer que es 'repeticiones', esto es, Words(palabra, repeticiones).

Answer (score 1):

Según lo que comentas, estás recibiendo un objeto con una estructura definida, por lo tanto el problema lo tienes al querer asignar la variable que luego pasarás a tu librería jQCloud.

**PROBLEMA**

Se desea obtener una variable que será pasada como parámetro al plugin [jQCloud](https://github.com/lucaong/jQCloud), para crear el *drawing* de "nube de palabras" en el elemento `div` con `id="demo"`.

**SOLUCIÓN**

Dado que el objeto que envías desde el `backend` tiene una estructura conocida, debes crear un `Array` de elementos que serán pasados como argumento a tu plugin.

Según tu comentario, el objeto que recibes tiene la siguiente estructura:

```
words = [
    { palabra: 'Palabra1', // Esto es un String
      repeticiones: 10 }, // Esto es un Number
    { palabra: 'Palabra2',
      repeticiones: 15 },
    // ...
]
```

La cual es una lista o array de objetos.

Debemos crear un `Array` cuyos elementos sean objetos con el siguiente formato: (tomado de la [documentación](https://github.com/lucaong/jQCloud) de jQCloud)

```
{text: "Lorem", weight: 15}
```

Para lograrlo, debemos iterar sobre la lista que recibes de tu backend y a cada objeto tipo `word` de tu lista, le extraemos el valor de `palabra` y `repeticiones` y lo almacenamos en un objeto cuyos atributos sean: `text` y `weight` respectivamente, luego, cada objeto debemos añadirlo a nuestro `Array` para luego pasarlo como parámetro a jQCloud.

Una forma de hacerlo puede ser la siguiente:

```html
<head>
  <link href="https://cdn.bootcss.com/jqcloud/1.0.4/jqcloud.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.bootcss.com/jqcloud/1.0.4/jqcloud-1.0.4.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    //Supongamos que la siguiente lista la obtienes de tu backend
    const words = [
      {palabra: 'Lorem', repeticiones: 4},
      {palabra: 'Ipsum', repeticiones: 10},
      {palabra: 'Dolor', repeticiones: 8},
      {palabra: 'Sit', repeticiones: 16},
      {palabra: 'Amet', repeticiones: 7},
      {palabra: 'Ana', repeticiones: 9}
    ];
    // creamos el array que pasaremos como parametro
    let words_array = [];
    //recorremos la lista recibida (usamos for ... of)
    for(word of words) {
      //usamos el método push de nuestro array para insertar los objetos
      words_array.push({text: word.palabra, weight: word.repeticiones});
    }
    $(function() {
      //ejecutamos la función jQCloud y le pasamos el array de elementos
      $('#demo').jQCloud(words_array);
      //console.log(words_array);
    });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <div style="width: 600px; height: 250px;" id="demo"></div>
</body>
```

Hemos usado el método [`for...of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Sentencias/for...of) que nos permite recorrer objetos iterables, en este caso recorremos el array que hemos recibido desde el backend.

Cada elemento del array lo asignamos a la variable `word` en cada iteración.

Luego, en cada iteración creamos un objeto con el formato requerido por jQCloud, usando los datos de nuestra variable `word`, y lo almacenamos en nuestro array `words_array`, usando el método [`push()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/push).

De esta forma ya tenemos el array que pasaremos como parámetro a la función jQCloud.

Espero que esto aclare tus dudas.

**EDICIÓN**

Dado que en tus comentarios me aclaras que el problema está en la forma de capturar en JavaScript la variable que envías al template usando Django, la solución no es tan trivial.

Sabiendo que usas la versión 1.10.5, no podrás hacer uso de [`json_script`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/templates/builtins/#json-script), que está disponible a partir de la versión 2.1

Sin embargo, puedes capturar el valor de tu variable asignándola a un elemento y colocando un atributo `id` a dicho elemento, que luego podrás volcar en una variable de Javascript usando `getelementById()`.

Un ejemplo de cómo lo podrías implementar:

**template.html**

```
<head>
  <link href="https://cdn.bootcss.com/jqcloud/1.0.4/jqcloud.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.bootcss.com/jqcloud/1.0.4/jqcloud-1.0.4.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div style="width: 600px; height: 250px;" id="demo"></div>
  <!-- Aqui ponemos el elemento que contendrá nuestra variable -->
  <!-- Podemos darle un estilo con 'visibility: hidden' si no queremos mostrar el div -->
  <div id="words" style="visibility: hidden">{{ words }}</div>
  <script>
    //Capturamos el valor de 'words' desde nuestro elemento div
    const words = document.getElementById('words').innerHTML;
    // podemos ver en consola el dato capturado
    console.log(words);
    // de aqui en adelante ya puedes trabajar con tu variable 'words' en Javascript
    // creamos el array que pasaremos como parametro
    let words_array = [];
    //recorremos la lista recibida (usamos for ... of)
    for(word of words) {
      //usamos el método push de nuestro array para insertar los objetos
      words_array.push({text: word.palabra, weight: word.repeticiones});
    }
    $(function() {
      //ejecutamos la función jQCloud y le pasamos el array de elementos
      $('#demo').jQCloud(words_array);
      //console.log(words_array);
    });
  </script>
</body>
```

Espero que de esta forma puedas resolver el problema.

Comment: El problema es que cuando hago eso, lo que recibe la constante words es lo siguiente: [&lt;Words: Words object&gt;, &lt;Words: Words object&gt;,...].

Comment: @Ana, ¿podrías subir cómo estás enviando los datos desde `views.py` y cómo los estás consumiendo? Ya que en la pregunta colocas: ***llegan correctamente al html (he probado esto haciendo una tabla y sacando los datos de cada objeto)***. Saludos

Comment: Lo acabo de editar, no se si con eso aclaro tus dudas, he intentado evitar código que no tenga que ver exclusivamente con el objeto "words". Gracias.

Comment: El template es html, y dentro tenía puesto el javascript que me has dicho, te lo acabo de poner todo.

Comment: ¿Qué versión de Django estás usando?

Comment: estoy usando la versión de Django==1.10.5